# Beginner: C program not adding

Tags: for-loop

Under the "for" statement one of the things im trying to do is add two dice and if they both add up to 15 just keep count of them. After the program runs print the number of times both dice add up to 15.

## error:The sum is always 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{


        int SEED, TIMES_ROLL,COUNT,DICE1,DICE2,PAIRS,SUM, SUM_COUNT;



        //Ask user for seed value
        printf("Type in a number for the seed value?\n");
        scanf("%d", &SEED);

        srand(SEED);
        SUM = 0;
        SUM_COUNT = 0;

        //Ask user how many times to roll the 2 dice
        printf("How many times would you like to roll the dice?\n");
        scanf("%d", &TIMES_ROLL);
        printf("ROLLING THE DICE..............\n");
        **for (COUNT = 1; COUNT < TIMES_ROLL +1;++COUNT)
        {
                DICE1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                DICE2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                if (COUNT <=10)
                    printf("%d and %d rolled\n", DICE1,DICE2);
                if (DICE1 == DICE2)
                    PAIRS = PAIRS + 1;
                SUM =  DICE1 + DICE2;
                if (SUM == 15)
                    SUM_COUNT = SUM_COUNT + 1;**


        }
printf("(%d WERE PAIRS)\n",PAIRS);
printf("(15 WAS THE SUM OF BOTH PAIRS %d TIMES)\n", SUM_COUNT);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `SUM` will never be `15` as range for variables `DICE1` and `DICE2` is `1...6` for both, and their sum range is `2...12`.

That is why condition `if (SUM == 15)` is always false and `SUM` variable is not changed.